# Splitting node from parent node in JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have DOM HTML like this

```
<div class="width_medium">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <div class="video">Video</div>
  <p>Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
</div>
```

And I want move away div class "video" from div "width_medium". Result will like this

```
<div class="width_medium">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
</div>
<div class="width_medium">
  <div class="video">Video</div>
</div>
<div class="width_medium">
  <p>Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
</div>
```

How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Hey, Can you tell me this HTML tag   <div class="video">Video</div> is always fixed ?

Comment: $('.video').wrap('<div class="width_medium">');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".video").unwrap();
$(".video").prevAll('p').wrapAll("<div class=width_medium></div>")
$(".video").nextAll('p').wrapAll("<div class=width_medium></div>")
$(".video").wrap("<div class=width_medium></div>")
```

```css
.width_medium p {
  background-color: blue
}

.width_medium .video {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width_medium">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <div class="video">Video</div>
  <p>Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
</div>
```

1. Unwrap the elements.
2. Use `.prevAll()` and `.nextAll()` and `.wrapAll()` to wrapp all prev and next p
3. Use `.wrap()` for the class video

**UPDATE**

Dont unwrap at first follow previous step then add `.parent()` to `.video` then use `unwrap()`

```js
$(".video").prevAll('p').wrapAll("<div class=width_medium></div>")
$(".video").nextAll('p').wrapAll("<div class=width_medium></div>")
$(".video").wrap("<div class=width_medium></div>")
$(".video").parent().unwrap();
```

```css
.width_medium p {
  background-color: blue
}

.width_medium .video {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width_medium">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <div class="video">Video</div>
  <p>Text 3</p>
  <p>Text 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This wouldn't quite work if the original div had p elements before or after it, would it?

Comment: it would work on current html markup though and that is what OP provided

Comment: Sure, but isn't there a variation to this code that could target that div regardless of what else is on the page?

Comment: @nnnnnn mate will update work base on what you ask earlier?

Comment: Thanks it work :D, Can you continue help me ? How can revert back to original with jQuery ?

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for critism it helps to make answers better and fitted for the OP

Comment: @DucPhamThe just do unwrap like  `$(".video").unwrap()` `$(".video").prev().find('p').unwrap()` you can handle the rest